# Why mediaPlayer.seekTo(msec) doesn't update surfaceView when mediaPlayer is paused?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I use `MediaPlayer` in my android app to play videos. When playback is paused via `mediaPlayer.pause()` method and I call `mediaPlayer.seekTo(msec)` the surfaceView I display video in is not updated. It displays the frame where the video was stopped when I called `pause()` method.

When I `start()` it again only then it starts from the frame I specified in `seekTo()` earlier.

How can I force `mediaPlayer` to update `surfaceView` when mediaPlayer is paused and not playing?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the gingerbread series OS. I fixed it when using onProgressChanged in the seekbar i actually call start, this updates the video to its proper position but still keeps the video at the same spot.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
{
    if(fromUser)
    {
    videoPlayer.seekTo(progress);
    setRemainingTime(progress);
    setPreviousTime(progress);
    playerPausedAt = progress;
    videoPlayer.start();
     }

}
```

the above code works quite well for me.